# What's the meaning of 「確認というか念を押しとくが」?

Tags: translation

> 確認というか念を押しとくが

I don't really get the meaning of this sentence. Does it mean *to remind*, *to confirm something*, or *to make sure of something*?

The whole sentence is:

> そう言えば
>   確認というか念を押しとくが

The context: two friends are talking and suddenly one says this line, changing the topic of the conversation.

Comment: Can you provide more context? What is the topic of the conversation? Maybe add the lines before/after this one.

Comment: Right. I added some more informations, unfortunately the sentences before are not related with this.

Comment: Ok, what about after? And is that `そう言うば` or `そう言えば`?

Comment: Sorry そう言えば and after he talks about his death..

Comment: A translation would be "By the way, I would like to confirm, more like I want to remind you, about [...]". The [...] part is the continuation of the sentence that you didn't put up.

Answer (score 1):

It is, to make sure of something or to confirm with no doubt

> 刑事は、最後にこう言った。もう一度、確認というか念を押しておきたいのですが、あなたは、事件のあった当日は、勤務先を、午後5時半ごろに、退社したのですね？
>
> The detective said. 'I want to make sure that you left your employer's office at 5:30pm that day. Is that correct?'

Answer (score 1):

"and by the way, to confirm or should I say make extra sure"

Comment: Welcome to the site. I just thought I should let you know that your answer was automatically flagged by the system as a potentially low-quality post given its length. You might want to add a little extra explanation or something beyond a one line translation to avoid that in the future!

Comment: this answer is good and concise as a translation of the OPs text.

Comment: @ssb thanks for the tip, ill keep that in mind

Comment: @sova I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad answer. Only that it was automatically flagged, and that explanation on why the given translation was chosen might make a better answer overall beyond just avoiding the flag

Answer (score 0):

そう言えば **確認というか**念を押しとくが

"Now that [you] mention it/that,  **To confirm or should I say**, stamp out [my] concern.."

The form A というか B is very common.  It means, roughly "A, or that is to say, B"

という is very important, it is a construction that "colloquially quotes" the preceding text.  Adding か adds a sense of questioning or variability.  It's like a verbal approximation.  "A... or more like... B"

Example in English:
Brandon: Are you shivering because you're cold?
Lisa: Not so much that I'm cold, I'm still shakey from that roller coaster ride!
= I'm cold というか still shivering from the roller coaster!

さむいと言うか, ジェットコ一スタ一 の影響で,まだブルブルしてる

---

You can also see this as というより or と言うより

A と言うより B : A, rather B.

Example (in English):
Cindy: You want to go to japan to learn clothing design?
Destiny: To learn clothing design と言うより, I want to satisfy my curiosity about Japanese culture.

---

At the end of this sentence is also the construction  念を押しとく

しとく is a contraction of しておく, which is a suffix used to say "in preparation for something" or "in anticipation of something i'll/we'll prepare this~" in this case it means something like "get rid of my concern (for sake of the future)" or "to just get it off my mind"